# how to create a foreign key where there are multipal primary key in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table A in a database which have multiple primary keys -`Primary key 1 and Primary key 2`.
Now I need the create a foreign key in another table having primary key 2 as foreign key

```sql
CREATE TABLE ADMIN_INFO(
    NAME VARCHAR(20),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(20),
    PHONE_NO VARCHAR(20),
    POST VARCHAR(20),
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(16) not null ,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(16),
    G_NAME VARCHAR(20) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_name,g_name)
);
```

```sql
CREATE tablE Godam(
    G_NO INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    BILLNO VARCHAR(20),
    MARK VARCHAR(20),
    QTY INT,
    REMARK VARCHAR(10),
    G_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY(G_NAME) REFERENCES ADMIN_INFO(G_NAME)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, as `G_NAME` column is not a primary key. You have created a composite key using two columns `USER_NAME` and `G_NAME`. So you need to have both columns in your second table `Godam` and create a foreign key using both the columns.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Godam(
    G_NO INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    BILLNO VARCHAR(20),
    MARK VARCHAR(20),
    QTY INT,
    REMARK VARCHAR(10),
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(16) not null ,
    G_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY(USER_NAME, G_NAME) REFERENCES ADMIN_INFO(user_name, G_NAME)
);
```

Comment: but is their a way to have a g_name only.. without user_name in Godam

Comment: if g_name is unique, then you can create primary key on that column and don't create a composite key and reference it as foreign key.